# Why is this bootstrap table uneditable by the user?

Tags: angular, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have just implemented this bootstrap table:
[image]

Here's its html definition:

```
<div class="card card">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="typo-line">
          <h4>Suivi des approbations</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- <h4 class="title">Table on Plain Background</h4> -->
        <!-- <p class="category">Here is a subtitle for this table</p> -->
      </div>
      <div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th *ngFor="let cell of tableData2.headerRow">{{ cell }}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of tableData2.dataRows">
              <td *ngFor="let cell of row">{{ cell }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's its relevant typescript code:
 ngOnInit(){

```
   this.tableData2 = {
        headerRow: [ 'Version', 'Approbateur(nom+fonction)',  'Principales remarques', 'Date d\'approbation'],
        dataRows: [
            ['', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', ''],

        ]
    };
```

The rows are not editable. So here are my questions:
1/ Why aren't the rows editable from the user side?
2/ How can I make them editable? Do I have to use forms?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you cannot able edit the elements in html except **input** tag.

But you can use the *attribute* **contenteditable**. this will make an element to editable.

so you can use like this,

```
    <tr contenteditable='true'>
     <th  *ngFor="let cell of tableData2.headerRow">{{ cell }}</th>          
</tr>
```

this will enable an entire row to be editable.